# Performing a bitwise sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

As part of a complex aggregate I want to know the *bitwise* sum of some data, i.e. if I have rows with values 1,1,1,2,2,8 the *bitwise* sum is 11. In this case the values are all exact powers of two (single bits), so I can hack around it by grouping and summing over the groups (obviously this example is a bit tortured compared to the real query):

```
select SUM(y.test)
from (
    select x.test
    from ( -- garbage test data
        select 1 as [test]
        union all select 1
        union all select 1
        union all select 2
        union all select 2
        union all select 8) x
group by x.test) y
```

but is there a clean way to perform a bitwise sum in [T]SQL?

Comment: Marc, are you basically talking about ORing all those values? Or do you mean removing duplicates first, then adding (not sure I'd use the term bitwise for that though)?

Comment: @paxdiablo both; bitwise OR over the set would be identical to unique add, since each is an absolute power of 2

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If all of your test values are single bits as in your example (1, 2, 8) - simply use `SUM(DISTINCT col)` in your query.

Hope that helps.

(For reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Its a bit convoluted but this does what you're after (note that ive included bit's up to 128, you may need to go higher, or may not need to go any higher than 8).

```
with data(i)
AS
(
    select 1 
        union all select 1
        union all select 1
        union all select 2
        union all select 2
        union all select 8
)
SELECT MAX(i & 1) +
MAX(i & 2) +
MAX(i & 4) +
MAX(i & 8) +
MAX(i & 16) +
MAX(i & 32) +
MAX(i & 64) +
MAX(i & 128)
from data
```

which can obviously be converted to a UDF if you so desire.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to convert this to a UDF. Can you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 2):

For single bits the SUM(DISTINCT col) is best answer but for multiple bits like 3 (=1 | 2) this doesn't work and best and quicker answer would be like this:

SELECT SUM(DISTINCT X.Text & T.B)
FROM X cross join (values (1),(2),(4),(8),(16),(32),(64),(128),(256),(512)) T(B)

Answer (score 1):

You have the operator | which performs bitwise or for 2 operands. It is possible to solve your problem using a cursor and this operator.

Edit
yes I mixed up and and or, fixed.